# Any way to tell Android OS to not use connected Wi-Fi network for "Internet"?

Tags: android

I cannot find any programmatic way to to notify the Android OS to route specific data over the Wi-Fi network (e.g., to and from addresses of a certain subnet), and all other data over the cellular modem.

**Reasoning**:  I am developing an embedded device that sets itself up as a Wi-Fi access point.  I want the phone to be able to connect to it via Wi-Fi to handle data intensive transfers (more intense than supported by Bluetooth), without "killing" the end-user's connectivity (e.g., via their cellular 3G/LTE modem).  The transfers can take minutes which would disable major functionality in the meantime given the phone will incorrectly try to route data over the Wi-Fi.

Is specifying certain data over certain interfaces at all possible?  Any way to avoid this?  I've seen solutions that periodically disable the W-Fi to let a little data through, but that's more of a hack than a solution.

Comment: Other ideas. Attempt to modify the dhcp server config on the wifi device such that the phone does not generate a default route through the wifi device. Or maybe use wifi direct.

Answer (score 1):

I think everything you need is in the [ConnectivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html) and [WifiManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html) classes.  Call [setNetworkPreference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#setNetworkPreference(int)).  And then use the technique described by **antiduh** to have your app connect using the other network.  (oops, it looks like he deleted his answer. Basically, your own app will enumerate local IP addresses and bind a socket to a specific IP address for the specific wifi network the app wants to connect on.

Comment: The problem is that the rest of the phone will use the "wifi" link, won't it? He's got a "wifi" device that can't route to the Internet

Comment: Ahh.... I see.  The phones can't connect to more than one wifi network at a time.  So when his app is running, he'll have to set the preferred network as the carrier (3g network), switch the wifi to connect to the embedded device, and then carefully restore everything back to normal when his app is done.  Sounds dicey.

Comment: Hmmm, I need to take a closer look at ConnectivityManager and WifiManager.  But it is more about the Wi-Fi network not being able to route to the Internet and needing to tell the OS to not route "most" data through it.  But I need to more carefully look in to your response!